# Would a few thousand unmatched/tied NYC addresses be a source data issue?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geocoding

Background: Am geocoding thousands of addresses, a process I am quite a novice too, using the NY State address composite locator. Using ArcMap 10.3.

14% remain tied and 12% unmatched. I'm inclined to think this is a source data issue but because of my inexperience I can't be sure.

A few notes:

1. The unmatched tied addresses are *almost* exclusively hyphenated addresses. But many of the addresses that were successfully matched are hyphenated as well.
2. It seems a handful of streets are the worst offenders for unmatched/tied addresses.
3. None of the matched addresses have a score below 100.

Comment: Can you please give an example of an hyphenated address that didn't match and one that did?  Are you able to manually match any addresses in the "worst offender" streets to see the differences?

Comment: @Miavalo Can manually rematch on these streets, and if by seeing the difference you mean in what they show for the address text in my datafram, it is the same. Example of an address that worked: "11-41 Neilson Street". Example of one that didn't: "11-02 Nameoke Street" (that is a worst offender street).

Answer (score 2):

This is not uncommon. New York is the most difficult region to obtain matched addresses to a location.
Even best geocoding engines struggle to provide match better than .7
There are few reasons, one is that geocoding engines still are not applying previous matches as IA, but most important that New York has very difficult address structure: state and city are matching and street names are just ugly.
Then you need to look if secondary address unit is present. That will bring down accuracy in New York to less than .7.

To be successful, please wire a two or three more backup systems to run over again the failed locations until you get them to 100%

Disclaimer: I work for batch geolocation service company at [CSV2GeoData](https://csv2geo.com)

Comment: by .7 you mean 70%? Further, What exactly do you mean by backup systems? If you mean a second locator, I created a composite of two locators provided by NYS (like I should have in the first place) and was able to boost my matching by a few points, while the remaining are all tied.